# the value is not loaded via Injection

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

There is a problem. I launch the application and an error appears: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaConsumerConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers' in value "${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}"  Tell me what to do?

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude =  {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase(DataSource ds) {
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:liquibase-changeLog.xml");
        liquibase.setDataSource(ds);
        return liquibase;
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration

public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String kafkaServer;
    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
    private String kafkaGroupId;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaServer);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, kafkaGroupId);
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "ru.job4j");
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, Passport> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<Integer, Passport> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }
}
```

file application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/managing
spring.datasource.username=pos
spring.datasource.password=pas
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
api-url=http://localhost:8080/api
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=app.1
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
server.port=8084
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

Comment: Configs seems alright! But you have crated `StringDeserializer` as your value deserializer and yet you have put something `Pasport` in your consumer factories.

Comment: until some time, all this worked for me, but after I added other modules, it stopped working

Answer (score 0):

Check the value spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092, I had same issue when the value was given properly, it's working.